# Handling names with leading dash in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, filenames

How can I handle (e.g. apply `mv` command) in a command shell the files with leading dash (`-`) in names? The command

```
mv -weirdfilename.zip normalfilename.zip
```

naturally accepts `-` at the beginning of a filename as an argument.

Answer (score 16):

Two ways:

- `--` indicates end of command options, so everything follows that are treated as arguments:

  ```
  mv -- -weirdfilename.zip normalfilename.zip
  ```
- Use `./` to indicate a file name explicitly:

  ```
  mv ./-weirdfilename.zip normalfilename.zip
  ```

Comment: It's worth noting that `--` might not always work for just `-` as a file name since it might have special meaning (e.g. stdin/stdout) in some programs.