# Is there any advantage in specifying './' in a for loop using a glob?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

I was under the impression it could be safer to use `./*.fastq` when searching for files ending with `.fastq`. For example, `./` would prevent capturing the file `.fastq`. This is obviously wrong, as shown in the example below:

```bsh
TMP_DIR=$(mktemp --directory)
mkdir -p ${TMP_DIR}
(cd ${TMP_DIR}
 touch {a,b,c,}.fastq
 ls -a
 echo ""

 echo "# match all:"
 for f in *.fastq ; do
     echo "${f}"
 done
 echo ""

 echo "# with ./:"
 for f in ./*.fastq ; do
     echo "${f}"
 done
)
rm -rf ${TMP_DIR}
```

```
.
..
a.fastq
b.fastq
c.fastq
.fastq

# match all:
a.fastq
b.fastq
c.fastq

# with ./:
./a.fastq
./b.fastq
./c.fastq
```

Neither `*.fastq` nor `./*.fastq` match the file `.fastq`. So I wonder now, is there any point using `./*.fastq` here, or `./*` in general?

Comment: The usual point to `./*` is that it ensures that names that start with `-` aren't treated as options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's initially surprising wildcard behavior, since the description for the `*` wildcard character says:

> Matches any string, including the null string.

... until you realize that period is slightly special when it's the *first* character of a filename.  The introductory text in `3.5.8 Filename Expansion` says it:

> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘.’ at the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set.

The "usage pattern" of prefixing wildcards with `./` is useful for [Handling names with leading dash in bash shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303929/handling-names-with-leading-dash-in-bash-shell), as steeldriver commented. It has no effect on the wildcard / filename expansion, but makes it safer/easier to handle the filenames when you refer to them, if they begin with characters that those programs might misinterpret as options. For example:

```
# I want a file named `-n`
$ touch -n
touch: invalid option -- 'n'
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
$ touch -- -n
### ok
$ touch ./-n
### ok
```

... and now that I *have* a file named `-n`, if I happen to loop over it with a wildcard:

```
for file in *n
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

... I get no output!

But if I prefix the wildcard with `./`,

```
for file in ./*n
do
  echo "$file"
done
./-n
```

... I see the filename.

This is a simple example for demonstration purposes; see also [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549) for this reason and others.  Other utilities will get tripped up by other options, so it's better to present the filenames to the utilities as safely as possible. If you *don't* prefix the wildcard to "escape" filenames, you'd have to "protect" your utilities in other ways; one *common* one is to signal the end of options with `--`, for example:

```
for file in *n
do
  mv -- "$file" backup/"$file"
done
```

... which will safely pass the `-n` filename to `mv` (as seen under `set -x`):

```
mv -- -n backup/-n
```