# `ls -d */` is not working on one specific directory

Tags: ls, troubleshooting

`ls -d */` runs fine in all other directories that I tried, but in one specifically, I get this:

```
ls: invalid option -- '/'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

I pasted the command in the terminal, so, it's exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: you might use a more specific regexp maybe like `ls -ld [a-z]*/` or something similar maybe

Comment: @francoisP: that worked

Comment: See also [Handling names with leading dash in bash shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303929/handling-names-with-leading-dash-in-bash-shell)

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have a directory named `-`, which `ls` is trying to parse as a marking series of options (or switches):

```
$ mkdir -- -
$ ls -d */
ls: unknown option -- /
$ -ls -d -- */
-/
```

Many core tools take a special switch, `--`, which means "No more switches; anything further is a normal argument".

Be wary of wildcards' use:

```
$ touch -- foo -i
$ ls
-i    foo
$ ls *
2251799814054385 foo
```

Just imagine the chaos that might ensue if you were using `rm` and there were a file called `-fr` in your current working directory.